Reinforce damaged load bearing studs
Getting reno done on a 30 year old home. One of the items was to have the electrician adding a power outlet next to a window. Came home from work and saw this and it almost gave me a heart attack - dude bored holes in both of the 2 by 6 studs right next to the window to around 2 1/2" deep, and he also damaged a good portion of one of the studs just to run the wires up.
Now I'm no expert but I know this is a load bearing exterior wall and these studs also support the the lintel above the window. Searched around, and found Ontario 9.23.5.3 stated that you cannot damage more than a third of the depth. The company agreed to reinforce with some strong ties and add a sistering stud on the side.
Will that suffice? It's hard to interpret what constitutes "suitably reinforced" per the building code.



Are you sure you hired an electrician and not a butcher?

Believe it a not, he is a licensed electrician (per the reno company at least), which begged the question how he got the license in the first place…

It's hard to know what is needed just from some close up pics. The definitive answer would need to come from an engineer.
That said, what the company said they would do seems reasonable. There are many products on the market now to reinforce damaged or broken studs, trusses, beams, joists and such.
As an opinion, it doesn't look like something that will ultimately cause the roof to collapse. If that is what you are worried about.

I agree, though I put little stock in metal scabs. They're a last resort and usually an unnecessary expense. Just adding an intact stud alongside is plenty.

I too don't understand how some of the metal "devices" really help correct the issue. However here in Fla. with new hurricane codes popping up, there are some really surprising bonding ties that have appeared.
